# Makefile make: Nothing to be done for `default'

Tags: linux, makefile, kernel

I write a hello.c:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/moudle.h>

static int hello_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "Hello, World\n");
    return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_ALERT "GoodBye, cruel Workd!\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
module_LICENSE("GPL");
module_AUTHOR("ChangZhi");
```

And this is Makefile:

```
obj-m := hello.o
KERNEL_DIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)
default:
make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
#clean:
#rm *.o *.ko *.mod.c

.PHONY:clean
```

when I run `make`, the shell displays `make: Nothing to be done for`default'.`. Could someone help me? Thanks a lot !

Comment: you shuld add `<TAB>` character in left of make -C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per ymonad says you require `TAB` before `make -C`

```
default:
    make -C $(KERNEL_DIR) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
```